# Convert array of arrays to string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Given an array of arrays with 2 vals such :

```
var arrayStd = [["G14",18],["G16",17],["G16",17],["G13",17]];
```

I currently use this or variations of this :

```js
var arrayStd = [["G14",18],["G16",17],["G16",17],["G13",17]];

var arrayToString = function(array){ 
  var str;
  array.map(function(a) {
    var item = a[0]+":"+a[1];
    str = str? str+'; '+item : item;
    } 
  );
return str
}
var str = arrayToString(arrayStd);
console.log(JSON.stringify(str));
```

Or

```js
var arrayStd = [["G14",18],["G16",17],["G16",17],["G13",17]];

var arrayToString = function(array){ 
  return str =  JSON.stringify(array).replace(/\"|\[\[|\]\]/g , "").replace(/\],\[/g , "; ").replace(/,/g , ":");
}
var str = arrayToString(arrayStd);
console.log(JSON.stringify(str));
```

**Is there a slicker way to do obtain str= "G14:18; G16:17; G16:17; G13:17"**

Comment: really no reason to use stringify, join("; ") will do it `[["G14",18],["G16",17],["G16",17],["G13",17]].map(i=>i.join(':')).join('; ')`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems like a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `let str = arrayStd.map(e => e.join(':')).join(';');`

Comment: Seems ```return str = array.join("; ").replace(/,/g,":")``` would do :D

Comment: *"Is there a slicker way to do"* No. That's perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.map()` and `.join()` like this:

```
let str = arrayStd.map(a => a.join(":")).join("; ");
```

**Demo:**

```js
let arrayStd = [["G14", 18], ["G16", 17], ["G16", 17], ["G13", 17]];

let str = arrayStd.map(a => a.join(":")).join("; ");

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Oh I see ! You enter deeper so you use ```map().join().join()``` and not ```join().replace()``` ! :D

Answer (score 2):

Making incremental improvements to your code...

You should be using `.forEach()` instead of `.map()` since you're not returning anything.

```js
var arrayStd = [
  ["G14", 18],
  ["G16", 17],
  ["G16", 17],
  ["G13", 17]
];

var arrayToString = function(array) {
  var str = "";
  array.forEach(function(a) {
    var item = a[0] + ":" + a[1];
    str = str ? str + '; ' + item : item;
  });
  return str
}
var str = arrayToString(arrayStd);
console.log(JSON.stringify(str));
```

---

However, `.map()` is actually useful here to map each inner array to a string, then take the new array of strings and join them.

```js
var arrayStd = [
  ["G14", 18],
  ["G16", 17],
  ["G16", 17],
  ["G13", 17]
];

var arrayToString = function(array) {
  var str = array.map(function(a) {
    return a[0] + ":" + a[1];
  }).join("; ");

  return str
}
var str = arrayToString(arrayStd);
console.log(JSON.stringify(str));
```

---

You can also use `.join()` on the inner array, and can get rid of the `str` variable by returning the result immediately.

```js
var arrayStd = [
  ["G14", 18],
  ["G16", 17],
  ["G16", 17],
  ["G13", 17]
];

var arrayToString = function(array) {
  return array.map(function(a) {
    return a.join(":");
  }).join("; ");
}
var str = arrayToString(arrayStd);
console.log(JSON.stringify(str));
```

---

Finally, in modern environments, you can convert your functions to "arrow functions" to get a more concise syntax.

```js
const arrayStd = [
  ["G14", 18],
  ["G16", 17],
  ["G16", 17],
  ["G13", 17]
];

const arrayToString = array => array.map(a => a.join(":")).join("; ")

var str = arrayToString(arrayStd);
console.log(JSON.stringify(str));
```

I also changed `var` to `const`, which is a good idea for variables you won't modify.

Answer (score 1):

Highly inspired by previous suggestions, yet shorter and more readable than others :

```js
var arrayStd = [["G14",18],["G16",17],["G16",17],["G13",17]];

var arrayToString = function(array){ 
  return array.join("; ").replace(/,/g,":")
}
console.log(arrayToString(arrayStd));
```

Comment: People generally won't do this because it's performing all the same joins, but then needs to go back and create a whole new strings after a search and replace. Does work though, as along as you can guarantee that there will be no commas in the provided text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use map function, and join the resulting array.

```js
let arrayStd = [["G14",18],["G16",17],["G16",17],["G13",17]];
//"G14:18; G16:17; G16:17; G13:17"

let arrayNew = arrayStd.map((elem,i) => `${i!==0?'; ':''}${elem[0]}:${elem[1]}`).join("");
console.log(arrayNew);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arrayStd = [["G14",18],["G16",17],["G16",17],["G13",17]];
//"G14:18; G16:17; G16:17; G13:17"

let arrayNew = arrayStd.map((elem,i) => `${i!==0?'; 
':''}${elem[0]}:${elem[1]}`).join("");
console.log(arrayNew);
```

Comment: Short but opaque.

Comment: The code is invalid. And this kind of template literal usage is very difficult to decipher.